# About the maximum number of arguments in Excel's STDEV function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

According to Excel's Help Center you can only use the STDEV function for up to 255 arguments.

> 1 to 255 number arguments corresponding to a sample of a population.

However, when I take the STDEV of an array of 10,000 values, I do get a number returned.

What's the deal here? Does Excel only take the first 255 values, or is the 255 limit in this case bogus and does it simply work fine?

Internet references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

255 **arguments** means 255 separate ranges or cell references (or even just numbers entered directly in the formula) but you can use a range as big as you like - e.g.  in STDEV(A1:A10000) there is only **one** argument, although there may be 10,000 values in the range.

So if you use that formula it will include **all** 10000 values in the STDEV

Comment: That is comforting. Thanks. But why does GEOMEAN then fail for a 10,000 values array? (It too has a 255 limit.)

Comment: That may be for different reasons, e.g. any negative number in the range means that you get #NUM error. Note that the 255 argument limit is standard for many functions (in Excel 2007 or later), e.g. SUM, AVERAGE, MIN, MAX all have a limit of 255 arguments

Comment: Well, that (a negative number) is not it, but maybe something else. 300+ seems to work. Anyway, thanks for clarifying. I hope you know what you are talking about. :)

Comment: When calculating GEOMEAN Excel firstly calculates the **product** of all values, so if that product exceeds the largest number that Excel can calculate then you may get an error, so the limit isn't a specific number of values but a set of values who's product exceeds a certain amount - see this thread at MrExcel for more details and possible workarounds - http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/2042-geomean.html

Comment: Note: that thread refers to a limit of 30 arguments - that was the old Excel 2003 limit before being increased to 255 in Excel 2007

Comment: Thanks for that too. I already figured the adding (or averaging) LNs out for myself. Which works fine. :) The LN as an array function was new to me. Works even better.

Comment: One more related question. Is there a max size to a range that you know of? Can I even make a 100,000 range (1 by 100,000) in Excel?

Comment: There's no limit except for the max dimensions of Excel - you can have a range as long as 2^20 (1048576) and as wide as 2^14 (16384)......although of course the size might affect performance